# How can I format my text?

Tags: java, text, string-formatting

**SOLVED**

Hi Guys so if I had a program that went like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tab extends JFrame
{
    public Tab()
    {
        super ("Swimming Pool Calculator");

        JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();

        // constructing the first panel
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel( "Welcome to blah,blah!", SwingConstants.CENTER); 

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add( l1 );
        tab.addTab( "Tab#1", null, p1, " Panel #1" );

        // constructing the second panel
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Welcome to JTabbedPaneDemo",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBackground( Color.blue );
        p2.add( l2 );
        tab.addTab( "Tab#2", null, p2, " Panel #2" );

    }
}
```

And I wanted the wording in JLabel l1 to say:

```
                                     "Welcome! 
                              Thank you for using the
                              Swimming Pool Calculator.
```

How would I do this?

I tried to use the `\n` for new line but that didn't work so well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing components understand some HTML

```
JLabel l1 = new JLabel( "<html><center>Welcome!<br>Thank you for using the<br>Swimming Pool Calculator.</center>");
```

Comment: Hi Thanks I just went and found something similar to this on Oracles tutorial site. Thanks again.